# how to add drop-down field in bootstrap contact form and what changes I need to do in php and contact_me.js?

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my Bootsrap code. I want to add a dropdown list but I'm not sure how it will work and what changes I need to do in PHP and `content_me.js`.

I tried doing some changes in php but it is not working.

Also, I want to put an <kbd>add more service</kbd> button which will appear when user selects an option from given drop down. If the user clicks the <kbd>add more</kbd> button that button disappears and a new dropdown shows up.

```html
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="service" id="service">
     <option>--Select your service--</option>
     <option value="1">option 1</option>
     <option value="2">option 2</option>
     <option value="3">option 3</option>
     <option value="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
   <div id="success"></div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>



<?php ob_start();
    // Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
 empty($_POST['email'])     ||
 empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
 empty($_POST['message'])   ||
 empty($_POST['service'])   ||
 !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$service = $_POST['service'];

    // Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message\n\nService:\n$service";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
ob_flush();?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors / issues did you encounter?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This is not a code writing service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

Comment: I tried putting this code in php but it is not working.

Comment: I tried putting this code in php but it is not working  empty($_POST['service'])  for dropdown list I am not sure how it works with drop down list value